# Why do getElementsByTagName() always returns an array?

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementsbytagname

Why is it that if I have only one `h1` element in the document, I still have to use the index to access it?

Like the following doesn't work.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('h1').innerHTML = "SHUSHAN";
```

but if I do

```
document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML = "SHUSHAN";
```

It does work.

Even though I only have one `h1`, why do I have to specify?

Comment: Because the return type is an array. Think about how much a pain it would be if that function sometimes returned an en element and sometimes returned an array of elements, that would be madness

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: This is so that you can have some sanity.

If you don't know whether you will get a single element or a collection of elements, you would have to write defensive, type-checking (stupid) code like this

```
let foo = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')
if (foo instanceof HTMLCollection)
  // do something with all elements
else
  // do something with just one element
```

It makes way more sense for the function to always return a known type, an `HTMLCollection` of `HTMLElement` objects

---

If you only care about getting the first element, you can use destructuring assignment

```
let [first] = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')
console.log(first) // outputs just the first h1
```

This is fine because the assignment clearly shows that it's expecting an array (or array-like) of elements but only cares about assigning an identifier to the first value

---

You should also be aware of the newer [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) functions …

- `document.querySelector` will select *at most* **one** element from the document or return`null`
- `document.querySelectorAll` will always return an `HTMLCollection`, but may be empty if no elements match the selector.

---

Here's how I'd write your code in 2017

```js
setTimeout($ => {
  // get the element to change
  let elem = document.querySelector('h1')
  // update the text of the element
  elem.textContent = 'SHUSHAN'
}, 3000)
```

```html
<h1>wait 3 seconds ...</h1>
```

Comment: Can you tell me what the $=> {...} of the setTimeout means?

Comment: It's just an anonymous function. It could be rewritten as `function () { ... }`

Answer (score 4):

getElement**s**ByTagName - the method name itself implies that it will return multiple elements - i.e. an array. The method always returns an array, with the length equal to the number of matching elements. As such you must always access the elements by the index of the element in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays must be accessed by index regardless of how many values it holds.  Do some reading on array data types to get a better understanding of the concept.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that `getElementsByTagName` always returns a  `HTMLCollection` of elements, which works mostly as an array. If there is only one element in this collection, then its index is `0`.

This is the reason why you must specify the index, even if there is only one element in the document.

Click [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp) or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) to see more documentation about this.