# Why does content of h1 tag doesnot change after clicking reset button?

Tags: javascript

```js
var one = document.getElementById("one");
var two = document.getElementById("two");
var reset = document.getElementById("reset");
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
one.addEventListener("click", function() {
  i = i + 1;
  document.querySelector("#d1").textContent = i;
});
two.addEventListener("click", function() {
  j = j + 1;
  document.querySelector("#d2").textContent = j;
});
reset.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1").innerHTML = "<h1>0 to 0</h1>";
});
// it doent work when i add textcontent in place of inner html

> why does content of h1 doesnot change when i click reset button.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Score Keeper</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1><span id="d1">0</span> to <span id="d2">0</span></h1><br>
  <p>Playing To : 5</p><br>
  <input type="number">
  <button id="one">Player One</button>
  <button id="two">Player Two</button>
  <button id="reset">Reset</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="score.js"></script>

</html>
```

> why does content of h1 doesnot change when i click reset button.

Comment: getElementsByTagName returns a node list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do getElementsByTagName() always returns an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42079587/why-do-getelementsbytagname-always-returns-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem  :

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns an array so you will need index you could use

```
document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "<h1>0 to 0</h1>";
```

But a better version is this :

```js
var one = document.getElementById("one"),
    two = document.getElementById("two"),
     reset = document.getElementById("reset"),
     i = 0, 
     j = 0;
one.addEventListener("click", function() {
  i ++;
  document.querySelector("#d1").textContent = i;
});
two.addEventListener("click", function() {
  j ++;
  document.querySelector("#d2").textContent = j;
});
reset.addEventListener("click", function() {
  i = 0 , j = 0
  document.getElementById("resetId").innerHTML = "<span id="d1">0</span> to <span id="d2">0</span>"; // Thanks to @Micheale
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Score Keeper</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id='resetId'><span id="d1">0</span> to <span id="d2">0</span></h1><br>
  <p>Playing To : 5</p><br>
  <input type="number">
  <button id="one">Player One</button>
  <button id="two">Player Two</button>
  <button id="reset">Reset</button>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="score.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Comment: Try clicking on one of the players after resetting

Answer (score 0):

You are using [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) which doesn't return a single element like [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). It returns an `HTMLCollection`/`NodeList` (depending on which browser), but you can just treat it like a standard array.

You should select the first element by using `getElementsByTagName[0]` instead.

You can either use `innerHTML` or `textContent`, but they do different things.

`innerHTML` would replace the contents of the `h1` tag with whatever you assign. So, `document.getElementsByTagName("h1").innerHTML = "<h1>0 to 0</h1>";` would output *two* `h1` elements, which you don't want.

So in either case, set `innerHTML` or `textContent` to  simply `0 to 0`

```js
var one = document.getElementById("one");
var two = document.getElementById("two");
var reset = document.getElementById("reset");
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
one.addEventListener("click", function() {
  i = i + 1;
  document.querySelector("#d1").textContent = i;
});
two.addEventListener("click", function() {
  j = j + 1;
  document.querySelector("#d2").textContent = j;
});
reset.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "0 to 0";
});
// it doent work when i add textcontent in place of inner html
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Score Keeper</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1><span id="d1">0</span> to <span id="d2">0</span></h1><br>
  <p>Playing To : 5</p><br>
  <input type="number">
  <button id="one">Player One</button>
  <button id="two">Player Two</button>
  <button id="reset">Reset</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName("h1")` returns an array so you have to select the `h1` you want.

Your code modified to take first `h1` (assuming it is always the good one).

```js
var one = document.getElementById("one");
var two = document.getElementById("two");
var reset = document.getElementById("reset");
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
one.addEventListener("click", function() {
  i = i + 1;
  document.querySelector("#d1").textContent = i;
});
two.addEventListener("click", function() {
  j = j + 1;
  document.querySelector("#d2").textContent = j;
});
reset.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = "<h1>0 to 0</h1>";
});
// it doent work when i add textcontent in place of inner html
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Score Keeper</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1><span id="d1">0</span> to <span id="d2">0</span></h1><br>
  <p>Playing To : 5</p><br>
  <input type="number">
  <button id="one">Player One</button>
  <button id="two">Player Two</button>
  <button id="reset">Reset</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="score.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Three problems here:

1- getElementsByTagName returns an array, not an element. You can retrieve the first element of the array with "[0]" as I've done in the snippet.

(I'd recommend giving that header an id.)

2- Problems with the innerHTML for h1. When replacing the h1 innerHTML, there's no need to repeat the h1 tags (you end up with nested h1s). But another problem is that you shouldn't forget the d1 and d2 spans, otherwise the code breaks.

3- Also, don't forget to reset i and j

```js
var one = document.getElementById("one");
var two = document.getElementById("two");
var reset = document.getElementById("reset");
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
one.addEventListener("click", function() {
  i = i + 1;
  document.querySelector("#d1").textContent = i;
});
two.addEventListener("click", function() {
  j = j + 1;
  document.querySelector("#d2").textContent = j;
});
reset.addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML = '<span id="d1">0</span> to <span id="d2">0</span>';
  i = j = 0;
});
// it doent work when i add textcontent in place of inner html
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Score Keeper</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1><span id="d1">0</span> to <span id="d2">0</span></h1><br>
  <p>Playing To : 5</p><br>
  <input type="number">
  <button id="one">Player One</button>
  <button id="two">Player Two</button>
  <button id="reset">Reset</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="score.js"></script>

</html>
```

EDIT: I see some other people have got here first, but I'll leave my answer up for now because the other answers don't maintain the spans with id d1 and d2, which makes the code fail after hitting reset